# Как сортировать двумерный ассоциативный массив по числовым значениям с сохранением ключей?

Tags: php, сортировка

Имеется:

```
$arr = ['cat' => '2', 'dog' => '4', 'pig' => '1'];
```

Нужно получить:

```
$arr = ['pig' => '1', 'cat' => '2', 'dog' => '4'];
```

Comment: Как насчёт чтения документации? https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.asort.php

Comment: Вы указали в качестве примера одномерный массив. Пример не соответствует вопросу.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = ['cat' => '2', 'dog' => '4', 'pig' => '1'];

uasort($arr, function($a, $b) {
    return $a - $b; // сортировка по возрастанию
});

print_r($arr);
```